# How to get a snapshot of old code with bitbucket?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I use bitbucket for VCS and I'd like to know how I get old versions of my project. I can browse the changesets but I don't know how I get a complete version like a snapshot of the project how it was last thursday and not just individual changesets. How can it be done? I've used github like that and it was a good function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitbucket is *not* a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_Control_System) (nor is GitHub). They simply host a clone of your [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System).

The easiest/best way to do what you ask is to use your local clone (or make a new one, see `hg help clone`) and then use `hg update` (or whatever) to get whatever version you want. (See `hg help update`.)

For people outside the project, if they don't want to use the DVCS directly for some reason, they can use Bitbucket's project download pages to download a tar-ball or zip file of tip or any tag or branch.